# js/jquery: copy contenteditable div to textarea, keeping newline info

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a contenteditable div. It starts out with some children. There is also a textarea. When "enter" is pressed, the contents of the div are copied to the textbox.

My problem is that any new elements, made by editing the div, are not copied with the same formatting as the original children;  the text is smushed together. Their html looks the same so this is odd. I need to see where a new line starts.

```
<div id = "e" contenteditable = "true">
    <div>line 1</div>
    <div>line 2</div>
</div>

<textarea id = "ta"></textarea>

// jquery
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {  //enter
       $('#ta').val($('#e').text());
    }
});
```

I edit the div, adding a few lines and pressing enter. The div now looks like this (Chrome inspect element):

```
<div id = "e" contenteditable = "true">
    <div>line 1</div>
    <div>line 2</div>
     <div>line 3</div>
     <div>line 4</div>
</div>
```

This also appears as 4 lines. However, in the textarea it looks like this:

```
line 1
line 2line3line4
```

I need it to look the same as on the page with 4 separate lines.

In this example, I could look at the div and add the line breaks myself. However, the editable div might actually contain much more complex html, the result of copy-paste.

(This is related to my wanting to clean up copy-pasted text. That seems to involve moving the text to a textarea and then back again. However, I need to know if a new line starts. )

Answer (score 1):

Change the java script for:

```
// jquery
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {  
        var result = '';
        $('#e > div').each(function (i, e) { 
            result = result + $(e).text().trim() + '\r';
        });
       $('#ta').val(result);
    }
});
```

Works fine for me! Hopes this help you!

Comment: Works great with the divs, but the html might not be divs, for example if I copy paste in an ol list. Then it doesn't work :( Sorry if that requirement was hidden further down in the question.

Comment: @user984003 you can change the selector as you want, I post $('#e > div') to awnser the question! You could change for any class, $('#e > div, ol') for exemple will get any text inside 'e' that are inside a div or ol. Hopes that this complete the question!

Comment: Right, but the thing is knowing all the selectors. What if it's a block span? Or a float:left? It can get quite complicated. I was hoping that copying to the textarea could solve this for me, the same as if it was manually copy-pasted to the textarea.

Comment: rather than guessing the element, just use `*` to match anything -- `$('#e > *').each...`

Answer (score 0):

Use oninput event listner

```
contenteditableDiv.addEventListener("input", function(){ 

       textAreaElement.value = contenteditableDiv.innerText;

      });
```

Comment: Oh, wow, four years later! :) I'm not using contenteditable anymore so I can't even test if this is right or even remember what my question was ;) Hopefully it can help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I think, it's like a inputtext more.. I hope help someone !

```
        function enteredDiv(cont) {
        $cont.keypress(function (e) {
           var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (keycode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var result = $cont.text().trim();
                $cont.text('');

                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is just deleting the contents when pressing ENTER, can't see how this is related to the question.