# Js/jquery: clean contenteditable copy-paste, same look as if manually copied to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, contenteditable

I want to clean the copy-paste contents before they are copy-pasted into my contenteditable div.

I want the text to look the same as if it had been manually copied into a text area. That means keeping line break information, but getting rid of styling, elements, etc.

I have seen the below answer, which involves moving everything to a textarea, the idea being to then move it back again. However, this loses ALL formatting, smushing the text together.

```
$('#e').on('paste', function() {
   setTimeout(function () {
        $('#textarea').val($('#e').text());
  }, 100);  
});
```

I asked a related question, but realize that I should ask for the end result, not assuming a certain way of solving it [js/jquery: copy contenteditable div to textarea, keeping newline info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593336/js-jquery-copy-contenteditable-div-to-textarea-keeping-newline-info)

Comment: Figure out where the formatting is being lost. `.text()` isn't removing it. I'd guess the action of copying or pasting the content is losing it.

Comment: Nope. When I copy-paste into the div, it still retains all the formatting - too much formatting (tag elements, css styles etc.)

Comment: That depends a lot from where you are pasting you text, if it is the word, or some random webpage, or another stuff... if i am not mistaken tinymce have a option to scrap the 'junk' out of the paste, try to check it out, but i dont really think you can do this in a easy way http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: Look here, no spaces tabs or linebreaks are being lost when not using copy/paste. http://jsfiddle.net/4jYpe/ therefore the loss you are seeing must be happening before that.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I'm thinking that dynamically added elements may just act differently when copied?? I actually wrote a related question because I wasn't really sure where in all this the solution lay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593336/js-jquery-copy-contenteditable-div-to-textarea-keeping-newline-info

Comment: Here's another fiddle demostrating that the issue is not related to jQuery or getting the text from the contenteditable: http://jsfiddle.net/4jYpe/5/ You'll notice that spaces and tabs are gone, but linebreaks aren't. I'm getting the data directly from the clipboard. I don't think you're going to be able to get all of the extra spaces and tabs like you are wanting on paste. It works here on SO because you're pasting into a textarea i think.

Comment: I will be Ok if I can just get the line breaks.

Comment: The sample i posted last does get the linebreaks, you just need to figure out where to insert it.

Comment: Hey, I think you nailed it! For IE, I had to change it to clipboardData.getData("text"). If you write it up as an answer then I will mark it as correct :) I'll now have to insert the cleaned text back into the div, based on the cursor location.